# RabbitMQ. Best practice for waiting for next message

Tags: c#, .net, rabbitmq

I have a receiver method in an ASP.NET Core web app:

```
    public void ReceiveMessage()
    {
        using (var connection = CreateConnection())
        using (var channel = connection.CreateModel())
        {
            channel.QueueDeclare(queue: "QueueName",durable: false,exclusive: false,autoDelete: false,arguments: null);

            channel.BasicQos(prefetchSize: 0, prefetchCount: 1, global: false);

            var consumer = new EventingBasicConsumer(channel);
            consumer.Received += (model, ea) =>
            {
                //Do something

                channel.BasicAck(deliveryTag: ea.DeliveryTag,multiple: false);
            };

            channel.BasicConsume(queue: "QueueName",autoAck: false,consumer: consumer);

            //BAD!!!
            while (true)
            {

            }
        }
    }
```

You'll notice I am using while(true) which smells bad. I basically need to keep this method alive and wonder how have other people done it?

This method should stay alive all the time and automatically process messages 1 by 1

Comment: In what context does this code run? A console app, a WinForms app, a website?

Comment: It's an ASP.NET Core web app

Comment: There is nothing wrong with a `while(true)`. You need to evaluate some expression in the loop, but beyond that, you have nothing wrong.

Comment: you may think about separating out this receiver into it's own application hosted separately from the web server. that way youre not consuming web server resources by monitoring the queue. this is a scalability issue and there's a fine line as to when this would need to happen. Ultimately your decision as to when this is necessary and it may never be necessary!

Answer (score 0):

You can create a **Hosted service** and consume your message inside it. This Hosted service is always alive and can receive all the messages.

```
public class ProductTopicConsumerService : ConsumerBase, IHostedService
{
    public ProductTopicConsumerService(ConnectionFactory connectionFactory)
     : base(connectionFactory, ExchangeTypes.topic)
    {
        try
        {
            Consume<ProductCreatedIntegrationEvent>();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Error => {ex?.Message}");
        } 
    }

    protected override string Exchange => "ProductExchangeTopic5";
    protected override string Queue => "Product.Updated5";
    protected override string AppId => "ProductCreatedConsumer";
    protected override string QueueAndExchangeRoutingKey => "Product.*";


    public virtual Task StartAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken) => Task.CompletedTask;

    public virtual Task StopAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        Dispose();
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
}
```

and **ConsumerBase** could be like this :

```
public abstract class ConsumerBase :  RabbitMqClientBase
{
    public ConsumerBase(ConnectionFactory connectionFactory, ExchangeTypes exchangeType)
        : base(connectionFactory, exchangeType,false)
    {
    }
    

    protected void Consume<TMessage>()
    {
        var consumer = new AsyncEventingBasicConsumer(Channel);
        consumer.Received += OnEventReceived<TMessage>;
        Channel.BasicConsume(queue: RefinedQueueName, autoAck: false, consumer: consumer);
    }

    private Task OnEventReceived<TMessage>(object sender, BasicDeliverEventArgs @event)
    {
        try
        {
            var body = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(@event.Body.ToArray());
            var message = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<TMessage>(body);

            ReceiveAction(message);

            Channel.BasicAck(@event.DeliveryTag, false);

            return Task.CompletedTask;

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Error occurred in OnEventReceived. Message: {ex?.Message}");
            Channel.BasicNack(@event.DeliveryTag, false, true);
            throw;
        }
        finally
        {
        }
    }

    protected virtual void ReceiveAction<TMessage>(TMessage message)
    {
         
    }

}
```

and finally, **rabbitMQBase** could be something like this :

```
 public abstract class RabbitMqClientBase : IDisposable
{
    protected const string VirtualHost = "MQ";
    protected abstract string Exchange { get; }
    protected abstract string Queue { get; }
    protected abstract string AppId { get; }
    protected abstract string QueueAndExchangeRoutingKey { get; }

    protected IModel Channel { get; private set; }
    private IConnection _connection;
    private readonly ConnectionFactory _connectionFactory;
    private readonly ExchangeTypes _exchangeType;
    private readonly bool _isPublisher;

    protected RabbitMqClientBase(ConnectionFactory connectionFactory, ExchangeTypes exchangeType, bool isPublisher)
    {            
        _connectionFactory = connectionFactory;
        this._exchangeType = exchangeType;
        this._isPublisher = isPublisher;
        ConnectToRabbitMq();
    }

    protected internal string RefinedExchangeName => $"{VirtualHost}.{Exchange}";
    protected internal string RefinedQueueName => $"{VirtualHost}.{Queue}";
    protected internal string RefinedRoutingKey => $"{VirtualHost}.{QueueAndExchangeRoutingKey}";
    private void ConnectToRabbitMq()
    {
        if (_connection == null || _connection.IsOpen == false)
        {
            _connection = _connectionFactory.CreateConnection();
        }

        if (Channel == null || Channel.IsOpen == false)
        {
            Channel = _connection.CreateModel();
            Channel.ExchangeDeclare(exchange: RefinedExchangeName, type: _exchangeType.ToString(), durable: true, autoDelete: false);
            if (!_isPublisher)
            {
                Channel.QueueDeclare(queue: RefinedQueueName, durable: true, exclusive: false, autoDelete: false);
                Channel.QueueBind(queue: RefinedQueueName, exchange: RefinedExchangeName, routingKey: RefinedRoutingKey);
            }
        }
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        Channel?.Close();
        Channel?.Dispose();
        Channel = null;

        _connection?.Close();
        _connection?.Dispose();
        _connection = null;
    }
}
```

and this is **Publisher|Prodcuer** class for RabbitMQ :

```
 public interface IRabbitMqProducer<in T>
{
    PublishResult Publish(T @event);
}

public abstract class ProducerBase<T> : RabbitMqClientBase, IRabbitMqProducer<T>
{

    protected ProducerBase(ConnectionFactory connectionFactory, ExchangeTypes exchangeType)
        : base(connectionFactory, exchangeType, true) { }

    public PublishResult Publish(T @event)
    {
        var result = new PublishResult();
        try
        {
            var body = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(@event));

            var properties = Channel.CreateBasicProperties();
            properties.AppId = AppId;
            properties.ContentType = "application/json";
            properties.DeliveryMode = 2; //persist mode
            properties.Timestamp = new AmqpTimestamp(DateTimeOffset.UtcNow.ToUnixTimeSeconds());

            Channel.BasicPublish(exchange: RefinedExchangeName, routingKey: RefinedRoutingKey, basicProperties: properties, body: body);

            result.SetSuccess();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            result.SetError(ex);
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

and for publishing your **publisher** should be like this:

```
 public class ProductTopicProducerService : ProducerBase<ProductCreatedIntegrationEvent>
{

    public ProductTopicProducerService(ConnectionFactory connectionFactory)
        : base(connectionFactory,ExchangeTypes.topic)
    {

    }

    protected override string Exchange => "ProductExchangeTopic5";
    protected override string Queue => "";
    protected override string AppId => "ProductCreatedConsumer";
    protected override string QueueAndExchangeRoutingKey => "Product.*";
}
```

and for **publish a new message** follow the below code:

```
var result = _producer.Publish(@event);

            if (!result.IsSuccess)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"Error => {result.Description}");
            }
```

Offsource you can simplify your consumer. but this is my experience to create a base class for **rabbitMQBase** and now both Publisher and consumer could use it.

Answer (score -1):

Take a look at the OWIN package - available in NuGet: Microsoft.Owin.Hosting

When you use it you are self-hosting the web service and your app would start with a call to:

```
WebApp.Start(queryServiceUrl, Startup);
```

Where "Startup" is a method to do all your initialization.  Your app/service stays running and will accept queries on the specified URL.

Comment: Hi Auction. I already do something like that with appLifetime.ApplicationStarted.Register(() => {CallReceiveMessage}. The problem is I have to keep spinning inside ReceiveMessage as if I don't, the connection and channel will go out of scope and I won't receive any more messages

Comment: It's hard to see how this answer is at all relevant to the question.

Answer (score -1):

Without a loop, the instant after you call `channel.BasicConsume`, the whole thing (connection/channel) will go out of scope and be immediately disposed/destroyed via the `using` statement. So, without the loop, your consumer doesn't actually consume anything.

To ensure the consumer operates, you need to have an infinite loop, with appropriate logic to exit when you shut down the program.  This is an unfortunate design of the .NET library for RabbitMQ, but it is what it is.

```
while (_isRunning & channel.IsOpen) {
    Thread.Sleep(1);
    // Other application logic here; e.g. periodically break out of the
    // loop to prevent unacknowledged messages from accumulating in the system
    // (if you don't, random effects will guarantee that they eventually build up)
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the advise. Would you have some sample code regarding this? Or an article about the "random affects" or best practices regarding when to "periodically break out..". I really appreciate anything else that might help

Comment: Well, periodically breaking out of the loop isn't really that hard, you'd just want to do it every few hours I suppose. I just noticed that unacked messages queued up after awhile and this helped with them - sort of an auto-purge of sorts. The messages will go back in the queue and be re-processed (or processed initially, as the case may be).